# Excel Steps Formula in Python

Tags: python, excel, text

So I am venturing into python scripts. I am a beginner, but i have been tasked with taking a excel formula to python code. I have a text file that contains 3+million rows, each row has three columns and is delimited by tab.

All rows comes as string and first two columns have no problem. Problem with third column is that the content when downloaded gets added padding of 0s to make 18 characters if data is numerical.

In the same column, there are also values that contain space in between. Like 00 5372. Some are fully text format either identified by letter or character like ABC3400 or 00-ab-fu-99 or 00-33-44-66.

```
A1      B1  Values            Output
AA00    dd  000000000000056484  56484
AB00    dd  00 564842   00 564842
AC00    dd  00-563554-f 00-563554-f
AD00    dd  STO45642    STO45642
AE00    dd   45632      45632
```

I need to clean this type of codes to make the output text to be clean, while

1. Leaving the spaces between,
2. Clean the leading and trailing spaces,
3. Clean the value if it is padded with 0's in front.

I do in excel for limited amount by using following formula.

```
=TRIM(IFERROR(IF((FIND(" ";A2))>=1;A2);TEXT(A2;0)))
```

*Semicolon due to regional language setting.
For large file, I use following power query steps.

```
= Table.ReplaceValue(#"Trimmed Text", each [Values], each if Text.Contains([Values]," ") then [Values] else if Number.From([Values]) is number then Text.TrimStart([Values],"0") else [Values],Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Values"})
```

First trim and then replace values. This does the job in Power Query very well. Now I would like to do it with Python Script. But as a noob I am stuck at very beginning. Can anyone help me with the library and code ?

My end target is to get the data saved in txt/csv with cleaned values.

[Excel ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4LUc.png)

*Edited to correct point 1) Leaving and not removing and further clarification with data.

Comment: you can achieve it by python library pandas,

Comment: Are there any spaces that you don't want to remove? i,e will there be spaces between words or numbers interntionally/?

Answer (score 0):

try the code below(replace the column1,column2,column3 with respectiove column names and provide file_address to variable file_name, if python script and excel file is saved at same location then only name will be enough):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(file_name, sep='\t', lineterminator='\r', skipinitialspace=True)
df['column1'] = df['column1'].str.replace(' ','')
df['column2'] = df['column2'].str.replace(' ','')
df['column3'] = df['column3'].str.replace(' ','')
df.to_csv('output.csv',index=False)
```

Comment: Hi It seems your solution is not working with my case, first of all lineterminator='\r', skipinitialspace=True) did not work, and second your steps are just cleaning the space string which i do not want from middle place, only preceeding and training. Also i want to remove 00s only if the characters inside the string is numerical.